# Hibernate @PreUpdate/@PrePersist inconsistency

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitylisteners

I'm experiencing a weird issue: I have an entity and a listener for that class,

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(Listener.class)
public class Foo {

    @Id long id;

    @ElementCollection Map<String, String> map;

    // getters and setters

}

public class Listener {

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void preUpdate(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        System.out.println(foo.getMap().size());
    }

}

@Stateless
public class TestDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void testMerge(Foo foo) {
        foo.getMap().put("foo", "test");
        System.out.println(foo);
        System.out.println(foo.getMap().size());
        this.em.merge(foo);
    }

}
```

and then when I execute `testMerge` I get this output (**updated** with SQL debug):

```
Foo@15bcfa3c
1
Foo@671144f9
0
Hibernate: insert into Foo values ( )
Hibernate: insert into Foo_map (Foo_id, map_KEY, map) values (?, ?, ?) // 1, 'foo', 'test'
```

so the map gets saved correctly on the database, but the entity passed to the listener has a empty map. What is happening?

**UPDATE**: Jira issue and test case
Related Jira issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11414
And test case: https://github.com/heruan/hibernate-testcase/tree/HHH-11414

Comment: is Foo a new entity or it has been already saved before?

Comment: In the test I'm running it's a new entity; I use `merge` since in the real scenario it could be a new one or an existing one.

Comment: Jira issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11414

Comment: You are aware that the instance given as argument to merge remains an unmanaged entity, and that merge returns a managed entity. So the instance you print in `testMerge` will never be the same as the instance in the listener!

Comment: I know that @KlausGroenbaek, I'm asking why the merged instance in the listener has an empty map.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a tricky one, but if you debug your testMerge code and the listener method, you might find out that the actual instances of Foo are different.
Now this is the case for @PreUpdate / @PostUpdate calls.

For the @PrePersist / @PostPersist this is not the case as the method always receives the same instance of the entity.

Not sure which version of Hibernate you are using, but i remember noticing that when i was doing a project some time ago for 3.x version.

**Update**

Just to remind you, as i was testing the merge along wiht Pre / Post Upate, i found out that the only time, the merge() operation can invoke an event listener is when it is invoked on a new entity which is not yet persisted. It then acts as a persist() operation itself and the @PrePersist annotated classes are called. So you might never be able to achieve what you seek for with that configuration.

Comment: I'm on the latest 5.2.6 and yes, I find the instances are different. What I don't understand is why I get an instance with an empty map, if the map is then saved correctly in the database. I'll do some more tests and report back here.

Comment: Try to use em.persist(..) just to see if you get the actual instance. Ill do some more tests later on

Comment: I split the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` and it seems that for new entities the `@PrePersist` method is called, but not with the same instance as you say: with a different one, where the map is empty.

Comment: Okay, using `em.persist` instead of `em.merge` triggers the `@PrePersist` with the same instance and the populated map. Unfortunately I need the map in the listener also when merging, and I can't understand why it's not there…

Comment: Besides the deifferent entities, i have updated the answer with what i stumbled upon some time ago ..

Comment: Try this (the update scenario) in the test. 1) em.find(Foo), em.detach(foo), em.merge(foo), update some field of the entity, no persist() or merge() after that so you just go out of the method. Do you get the @Preupdate listener method called?

Comment: If I update the map, it does not get called. After many tests, this is the outcome: upon `merge`, listeners are invoked with an instance of the entity on which elements of `@ElementCollection` fields are not copied into. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes and on top of that you will not get a @PreUpdate call with merge. There are many things to improve in the api...

Comment: Solve the `@PreUpdate` call adding a `@Version` field. But still, no map in the callbacks… I'll fire an issue in Hibernate Jira.